# Use nginx directive to look for a jpg in another location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a general nginx rule to serve jpgs from their URI.

So if the URI is "http://example.com/images/1.jpg" it will serve under the form root of the site/images/1.jpg

I want to try and serve the image from alternative path if not found on the original path. How do I write the second location?

Here is what I got:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf|ico)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
            access_log      off;
            expires         max;
            log_not_found   off;
    }
```

How do I write the fallback to look for the files in another location like /home/user/anotherfolder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a named capture in the regular expression `location` to save the filename for later. You can cascade named locations, to try different roots:

```
location ~* ^/images(?<filename>/.+\.jpg)$ {
    try_files $uri @other;
}
location @other {
    root /path/to/alternate;
    try_files $filename @fallback;
}
```

If there is a suitable common parent directory, you can achieve the same thing in a single location block.

```
location ~* ^/images(?<filename>/.+\.jpg)$ {
    root /path/to/ancestor;
    try_files /dir/$uri /other/dir/$filename @fallback;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my issue is that I need to ignore the full URI and just look for the file - so in the above example I need to ignore the images part of the uri and only search for 1.jpg in a new location